# Как проверить невидимую Recaptcha V2 на JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

Проверяю `recaptcha v2` на стороне `js` с помощью следующего кода:

```
grecaptcha.getResponse().length == 0
```

Но с невидимой этот код не работает. Каким образом можно проверить невидимую `recaptcha` перед отправкой формы?

Comment: Что означает `невидимая` Вы прячите виджет или как это у Вас происходит?

Comment: @DaniilLoban, установлен параметр "Тип reCAPTCHA:Версия 2 – невидимый значок" - она есть в виде значка на странице, но устанавливать галочку вручную не нужно. Перед отправкой данных должна проверяться ReCaptcha - иногда в процессе проверки появляется окно с вводом от Google. И только по окончании проверки - отправлять данные на сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу то ответ находится в [документации](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) в последнем скрипте на странице. Проверка делается через `grecaptcha.execute()`. Код проверил на своем домене, зарегестрировав `v2 invisible` перед отправкой формы если она заполнена происходит валидация. Понятное дело что скрипт модифицируется под конкретную задачу, способом навешивания обработчика и самой функцией `validate`

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
      alert('thanks ' + document.getElementById('field').value);
    }

    function validate(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (!document.getElementById('field').value) {
        alert("You must add text to the required field");
      } else {
        grecaptcha.execute();
      }
    }

    function onload() {
      var element = document.getElementById('submit');
      element.onclick = validate;
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      Name: (required) <input id="field" name="field">
      <div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha"
          data-sitekey="_your_site_key_"
          data-callback="onSubmit"
          data-size="invisible"></div>
      <button id="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>onload();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что на сайте самодельная форма, не через тег "form", и переделывать ее нет возможности. Отправка производится через Ajax - нужно как-то в этот Ajax встроить ReCaptcha и проверить правильность на сервере.

Comment: Про ajax можно было конечно и в вопросе написать) никаких проблем нет перед вызовом ajax делаете тоже самое, добавьте минимальный код в вопрос (без лишних деталей) чтобы я смог продемонстировать как это сделать в Вашем случае.